# Encrypt Terraform values in Gitlab

Tags: azure, encryption, gitlab, terraform, azure-keyvault

I have the following flow:

1. You work on Terraform code locally
2. You push the code to Gitlab
3. Gitlab pipeline automatically run terraform init, terraform plan and terraform apply (manually)

The question is about secrets. I need to place them to Azure KeyVault, thus I have "value" field in Terraform code, which cannot be placed to Gitlab as plain text. If I place secrets to file and decrypt a file using "git-crypt" - it gets to Gitlab encrypted and Terraform sees it as encrypted already and creates an encrypted secret.
Any ideas how to do it?

I'm creating the secret via Terraform this way:

```
  resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  value        = "szechuan"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

Comment: What kind of secrets? Any TF code example? Usually you setup secrets outside of your TF, e.g. using independent process.

Comment: @Marcin It's a KeyVault secret with a hardcoded value. The only alternative that I see is to create it manually

Comment: This is bad design and you shouldn't be doing this. All data, including your secret, will be in **pain text** in a state file. As mentioned, you have to do it **outside** of TF for maximum security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pls provide TF code here. If you fetch keys from keyvault using 'data' block, then it should not be placed in plain text format in GitLab. Still would request you to put codes here, so that I can understand better.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to fetch secret from KeyVault, I'm creating a secret using KeyVault, with hardcoded value for this secret. Added example

Comment: if you store keys in keyvault, then I think you will need to fetch keys at some point. 

If you don't want to fetch that, then I would recommend to store keys in secret manner in gitlab runner which is backend executor of gitlab. In value argument, you can use function 'file' like value = file("my_secret_file") . Inside the file func, you need to provide the path of file. Using this function, secret file would be loaded and secret value would be placed without fetching.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your advice about Gitlab runner. I didn't think about it, but it seems the best suggestion.